# Sending value to smart contract failed on Testnet Rinkeby, Ropsten via MetaMask

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation, ropsten, etherscan, rinkeby

I'm facing an issue with sending value to my smart contract. I created a very simple smart contract and deployed it using MetaMask & Remix to Ropsten Testnet. Contract created successfully.

Now I'm trying to send some value to my contract address and its continuously failing. I have tried this on different Testnets too e.g Rinkeby but same error.

> "Value transfer did not complete, most likely as a result of REVERT opcode "

**Contract code**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract HelloWorld {  
    event log_string(bytes32 log); // Event

    function () public { // Fallback Function
        log_string("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

[Transaction for contract creation](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc7a765cae969a2ee231f66de57e4106eec44b3b2e15b6c985894ce0b05f5a3c5)
[Transaction for sending value](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xbbe7dbfb37608319758be371930acce289910271a116f779610faed2382e1836)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction you linked to has ether attached to it (0.5 ether), but the function you're calling (the fallback function) is not marked `payable`. If you want to be allowed to send ether to this function, use:

```
function () public payable { ... }
```

See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/15/writing-a-contract-that-handles-ether/.